# Angular material not working in Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

Hi im currently working on a demo app and im currently working on ruby on rails, i want to implement angular material for my front end but when importing angular.js and angular.css like this. 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>`

and my application.js consist of.

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require turbolinks 
//= require_tree . 
//= require angular-material`

and my application.css has.

`*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require angular-material`

when trying to use the sample on angular material button. it only display the text . for example the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <title>DEMO RUBY ON RAILS</title>
    <h2>DEMO RUBY ON RAILS</h2>
        <p>HELLO <%= @name %></p>
        <%= link_to('HELLO INDEX RUBY',{:action => 'hello'})%><br/>
        <%= link_to('HELLO WITH PARAMETERS RUBY',{:action => 'hello', :page =>5, :id=>20})%> 
        <md-button md-no-ink class="md-primary">Primary (md-noink)</md-button
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

it only display the button with text Primary. it does not display the button itself.

[image]

i really appreciate your answers. thanks

Comment: Is there any error on console?

Comment: None, that's the weird part. it also loads the the following js and cs successfully.

css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic
angular-material.min.css
docs.css
angular-logo.svg
preload.js
angular.min.js
angular-animate.min.js
angular-route.min.js
angular-material.min.js
docs.js
angular-messages.min.js
angular-aria.min.js
docs-demo-scripts.js

Answer (score 0):

I've seen an issue with `turbolink` is not playing nicely with JQuery. One of my college had an issue with integrating `material` design for a rails project with turbolinks.

So try removing `turbolinks` from both `application.css` and `application.js`

Remove `//= require turbolinks` from `application.js`

Comment: it's still the same. nothing happened

Comment: I can see your button tag is not closed `<md-button` correctly, it should be `</md-button>` , if that is same in the code, try fixing it

Comment: It's closed. it's just a typo.

Comment: do u have `rails-angular-material` gem in your Gemfile (https://github.com/alexkpek/rails-angular-material) ?

Comment: Yes there is. this was my gem file looks like.
gem 'rails', '4.0.0', gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18',  gem 'activerecord- native_db_types_override' gem 'rails-angular-material', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.5' etc. etc